# iOS: how to exclude pre iPhone 5s devices from universal app without excluding pre 4th generation iPads?

Tags: ios, universal

We have an application for iPad (compatible to all iPads running iOS 6.0 and above, so only 1st generation iPads are excluded generally).

Now we are working on an iPhone version and would like to release it as a universal upgrade to the existing app (since universal apps seem to rank better in the appstore than apps with individual versions).

However - for iPhone we would like to exclude all pre iPhone 5s devices. The only way I know of to exclude devices is by having RequiredDeviceCapabilities in the info.plist - and going by this list https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html to exclude pre iPhone5s devices one needs to require either OpenGL ES 3.0 or metal. However, in a universal app I guess this would also exclude all pre 4th generation iPads.

So - is there any way, in a universal ios app - to exclude pre 5s iPhones but still allow the app to be downloaded to all iPads (except for 1st generation, which is excluded by minimum iOS)?

Comment: My first question is, why exlcude pre iPhone 5S device at all?

Comment: It's because of performance and screensize. The projected porting workflow will create a product that will run fine on iPhone 5s but suboptimally on iPhone 5. Performance optimization is not budgeted for now. Pre iPhone 5 devices's smaller screen-size we do not want to support either. Therefore, considering budget/audience reach we want to target only iPhone5s upwards (actually, for screensize we would prefere to target only iPhone6 upwards, but this does not seem to be possible)

Comment: Well you are out of luck, since you can only target the iPhone you want with the OpenGL ES 3.0 check. Thus loosing the older iPad. Also I can not image that the app will preform ok on an iPad 2 and not on an iPhone 5.

Comment: You can't restrict AppStore apps for specific devices only iOS versions. You could refuse to run on those devices but risk pissing off customer (and likely Apple will reject you for this behavior anyway).